# Where does the purchasing currency go?

Tags: trading

When someone purchases Bitcoin, where does the currency go used to pay for it? It can't just disappear. It still has value to someone.Thank you.

Comment: Where does the money go when you pay for an apple at the supermarket?

Answer (score 2):

It goes to the person (or people) who sold the Bitcoin